# How to enable SAML Authentication for aws private api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml

Architecture : Strictly Serverless
Cloud - AWS

I've an application load balancer (internal) in front of a private api gateway and the requirement is to protect the load balancer endpoint with the enterprise SAML IdP. 
Lambdas, S3 are allowed, but Route 53, EC2 are not whitelisted to use on this account.

Problem here is what would be the relay state (final target) here after SAML authentication ? As the internal ALB and the private api gateway endpoints arent visible outside the AWS landscape, I dont understand how to land on the alb endpoint once the user is authenticated with the enterprise IdP ?

Many thannks !

Comment: Will they be accessing the ALB via Lambda (over the internet) or will they be using private channels (VPN, Direct Connect) to connect to the private ALB directly? Are your lambda functions running inside your VPC?

Comment: @JorgeGarcia - VPN, Dx connectivity. Yes, all the lambda functions are attached to a VPC.

Comment: Did my answer help make things more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the on-premise enterprise IdP with your ALB, the **IdP and ALB must be able to talk to each other (via VPN or Direct Connect)**. you would then **establish a trust relationship** between your AWS account and the IdP and **define an authentication action in a listener rule on your ALB**.

Elastic Load Balancing uses the OIDC authorization code flow:

1. When users direct requests to your ALB, the ALB authentication
   action will check if the session cookie exists on the incoming
   requests and check its validity. If the session cookie is set and
   valid then the ALB will route the request to the proper target group
   containing identity information (JWT token via X-AMZN-OIDC-*
   headers) that backend instances can use to identify the user. If the
   cookie is not present, the load balancer redirects the user to the
   IdP authorization endpoint so that the IdP can authenticate the
   user.
2. The IdP then authenticates the user and redirects the user back to
   the load balancer with an authorization code. The ALB presents the
   code to the IdP token endpoint to get the ID token and access token.
3. After the load balancer validates the ID token, it exchanges the
   access token with the IdP user info endpoint to get the user claims.
4. The load balancer creates the authentication session cookie and
   sends it to the client so that the client can use it on subsequent
   requests.

Source:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/